# Where are AWS CodeDeploy Deployment logs found?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I can see the logs in the AWS Console under Codedeploy, when I select the deployment and then click `choose events`, but they appear to be truncated.  If I SSH into the instance, where are those codedeploy deployment logs located?

I see logs in `/var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent`, but the logs there don't match what's in CodeDeploy.

I'm running on Amazon Linux.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I've figured it out.  The deployment logs are found in:

`/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/deployment-logs/codedeploy-agent-deployments.log`

Each deployment also keeps its logs in:

`/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/88f9d1cf-4ee4-4b0c-9458-b1d41b8d4b48/d-TTUV9E8BG/logs/script.log` where `88f9d1cf-4ee4-4b0c-9458-b1d41b8d4b48/d-TTUV9E8BG` is different for each deployment.

On windows this appears to be:

`C:\ProgramData\Amazon\CodeDeploy<DEPLOYMENT-GROUP-ID><DEPLOYMENT-ID>\logs\scripts.log`

Source: https://github.com/aws/aws-codedeploy-agent/issues/8

Answer (score 14):

Linux Deployment Logs (Not the same as original answer):

```
/var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log
```

Linux Script Logs:

```
/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/deployment-group-ID/deployment-ID/logs/scripts.log
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployments-view-logs.html

Answer (score 4):

If you've found this question and you're looking for Windows logs, they are next to the userdata logs, in

```
C:\ProgramData\Amazon\CodeDeploy\log\
C:\ProgramData\Amazon\CodeDeploy\deployment-logs\codedeploy-agent-deployments.log
```

The \log\ folder contains the logs for the agent itself, showing that it's running and checking for updates.  The deployment-logs contains the output of the deployment scripts, that's probably the one you want.

(programData is a hidden folder which requires administrative permissions)

Comment: The whole time I was looking under "C:\Program Files". Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 3):

log in to your ec2 instance with the command

```
ssh -i {KeyPair.pem-locations to keys file here} ec2-user@10.xxx.xx.xxx{your instance ip here}
```

go to below location, you will have logs here

```
/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/deployment-logs/codedeploy-agent-deployments.log
```

use the command

```
cat codedeploy-agent-deployments.log
```

with this you can open the log file in the commandline itself if your ec2 is a linux instance and if you are working on linux.
copy it and paste it somewhere in your local machine so you can further explore the logs without any hassle.

`